# Method reference throws while supplier works

Tags: java, java-8

I have this issue that to me seems strange:

```
Person p = null;

Supplier<String> s = p::getName; // Throws NPE immediately

Supplier<String> s2 = () -> p.getName();
s2.get(); // Throws NPE after get() call
```

How come both *s* and *s2* are Suppliers, yet work so differently?

I'd expect *s* to throw NPE after calling *s.get()*, not immediately.

Why is that? What's happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider also the difference between `methodReturningAPerson()::getName` and `() -> methodReturningAPerson().getName()`: the former invokes `methodReturningAPerson()` once; the latter invokes it every time the supplier is invoked.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating, couldn't find a good thread on SO.

Comment: It's not an especially easy thing to search for (my search for [site:stackoverflow.com java npe method reference supplier](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+npe+method+reference+supplier) didn't show up this result in the first page).